# Understanding why a problem was solved a certain way

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, education

I have this question in one-dimensional kinematics and the way the book solves it has left me confused. Here's the question:

```
A speeder is doing 40.0 mi/h in a 25 mi/h zone approaches a parked police car. The instant
the speeder passes the police car, the police begins its pursuit. If the speeder maintains
a constant velocity, and the police car accelerates with a constant acceleration of
4.51 m/s^2, how long does it take for the police car to catch the speeder?
```

The book says to find the displacement and by using ($x - x_i = v_it + 1/2at^2$) and ($Δx = v_s\times t$) for the speeder. Then they make the two equations equal each other and come up with the equation ($t = 2v_s/a$) I do not understand why you have to make them equal each other.

Comment: The questions ask about the time at which the police *"catch the speeder"*. How can you define that idea in terms of concepts available in kinematics?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking me (sorry, I'm slow). Do you mean velocity vs time or something similar? If so, I would define it as position vs. time. Though, I still don't understand.

Comment: The act of "catching" would be position versus time? Are you sure?

Comment: @cress: See: [http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/~pqh/201_3n.pdf](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/~pqh/201_3n.pdf)

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all. The act of catching involves how fast each "object" is going and how far apart they are from each other. I don't know how to say that in a definition using kinematics.

Comment: How far apart are they when "catch" happens? And why does "velocity" have anything to do with it?

Comment: Ooh, I see. They would be right next to each other. For velocity, how would you catch someone if you are not moving? Am I over thinking this?

Comment: $x - x_i = v_i + 1/2at^2$ Does the book really say this, or is $v_i$ multiplied by $t$?

Comment: @DavePhD Oh sorry, that was a typo. It is $v_i$ * t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you and the book should do is agree what is time zero. It makes sense here to set $t=0$ when the car passes the stationary police car.

Then the distance traveled by the speeder is $\Delta x = u_s t$ and the distance traveled by the police car is $\Delta x = \frac{1}{2} a t^2$.

The book equates the two to find the time, and distance it takes for the cop to catch the car. There are two equations and two unknowns ($\Delta x$ and $t$).

Does this explanation help?

Comment: A little bit. Is it because the question is asking how long it takes for the cop to be side by side of the speeder? Which would be the reason why you equate the two?

Comment: Yes, you got it.